# Symfony defining Foreign key

Tags: symfony, entities, erd

[This is my ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sMlR.png)

I need help with how to associate the foreign keys with my entities
from what i know is that it has to something with this kind of code:

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
```

TL;DR I made entities but now i need to associate the foreign keys (image) but i don't know how.

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="klant", mappedBy="Bestellingorder")
     */
    private $klanten;



/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Bestellingorder", inversedBy="klanten")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Bestellingorder_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $Bestellingorder;
```

[Creation Error] The annotation @ORM\ManyToOne declared on property TuinBundle\
  Entity\Bestellingorder::$klanten does not have a property named "mappedBy". Ava
  ilable properties: targetEntity, cascade, fetch, inversedBy

stuck here.

Comment: Please read [how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Yes indeed, it is "something like this kind of code" . What issue did you encountered while using it?

Comment: I can't figure out what to fill in.

Comment: Read that document please, you'll see what you need.[Association Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional) . After update schema.

Answer (score 0):

Try with that :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="klant", inversedBy="Bestellingorder")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="klant_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $klanten;



/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Bestellingorder", mappedBy="klanten")
*/
private $Bestellingorder;
```

But i don't understand why you have sometimes "klant" or "klanten", didn't make sense for me. What is the name of your entity ? klant or klanten ?

Comment: Don't worry i fixed it the same day. what i did wrong was that i used the code for the opposite files which made that error. I just had to swap and edit them a bit. But appriciate it.

Comment: Ok, fine so ! Put your answer or accept an answer as the best/good one so the subject is registered as solved and can help the other person who will have the same issue